Need help in optimizing Dry Etching Model in Python for Performance
I am working with a dry etching simulation model taken from a Github repository, which was originally developed in Python 3.6 (version 0). I modified the code so that it runs in Python 3.11, but I am facing performance issues. Currently, the code takes around 22-24 seconds to process a single image, which seems quite slow for my machine. I am wondering if this processing time is typical for this model or if there are any optimization techniques that I could apply to improve the performance.
My machine specifications are:

Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4440 CPU @ 3.10GHz
8GB RAM
Windows 10

Is the processing time I am experiencing normal for this kind of simulation, or should it be faster?
Are there any specific optimizations or hardware requirements that could help speed up the performance?
I have tried modifying the code to run in Python 3.11, as it was originally designed for Python 3.6. I was expecting that the code would run with similar or slightly improved performance since I am using a more recent version of Python. However, the processing time remains quite long, and I am unsure if this is expected behavior for the model or if there are potential optimizations that I haven’t considered.
I also wondered if there are any specific machine specifications or software dependencies that could be affecting the speed. Any insights or suggestions on how to improve the processing speed would be greatly appreciated.

question is off-topic. needs a lot more focus. [ask], [help/on-topic], [help/dont-ask]

The Python developpment team has focused a great part of its work on performance improvement lately (https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.11.html#optimizations for 3.11 but check also 3.12 and 3.13) so I'm very surprised that you experience slower performances compared to 3.6. I'm also surprised you had to make substantial alterations to the code to port it from 3.6 to 3.11.  Could you provide more details on what you did? What are the initial processing time (3.6) and the current one (3.11)?

@el_grezeq Thank you for your response! I haven’t tested the code in Python 3.6. I needed it to run in Python 3.11 for compatibility with my setup, so I modified it directly from the GitHub repo (written for Python 3.6). The processing time I mentioned (22-24 seconds per image) is for Python 3.11 on my machine. I can’t compare it to Python 3.6, as I never used that version. The changes I made were minimal—just a few adjustments for compatibility. I’m wondering if this processing time is normal or if there’s room for optimization. Happy to share more details if needed

The code is pretty big and we have no idea on what to focus on specifically. You must either write a much smaller minimal reproducible example (and include it in the question), or profile the code so to know what to focus on and what to optimize. The former is better since we can easily profile a small reproducible code ourself so to then guide you.

Regarding the newer version of CPython, an efficient Numpy code should not be impacted much by the version of CPython so I guess we can conclude the code is not efficient and might be optimized.

By the way, please check you clearly have enough RAM: memory swapping can makes code MUCH slower (and new CPython versions might use more memory for sake of performance).

OP also opened an issue: https://github.com/cococastano/PythonDryEtchModel/issues/1

Your question is too broad to be answered simply: 1. Is the processing time "normal"? Maybe, this is a very specific use case. 2. Are there any specific optimizations? Maybe, but don't expect people here to go through the entire Github repo to give you answers. 3. Are there any specific hardware requirements? Not really but your config is not tailored for heavy scientific computations. 4. Would using Python 3.11 instead of 3.6 improve performance? Likely not or not by a large margin. 5. How to improve the processing speed? Most likely by vectorizing part of the code.

From there you have two options IMO:  1. Deep dive into the code and analyse the bottlenecks, i.e. the parts that take the most time. You can use a profiler to do this. Then try some common optimization techniques. If you still have specific questions then come back here.   2.  Do nothing. I understand that you are not a computer science major. Do you really need to spend time trying to optimize this code? Couldn't you for example run these simulations overnight or during your lunch break?

From the author of the package: "I am not a coder, so my code is messy. I would be happy for a savy coder to come along and clean up this work and maybe create more elegant classes" Probably not only messy but also slow. Profile the code as Jerome mentioned, find bottlenecks, fix them yourself or come back here with some specific example of code to improve.
